# Progress bar not working with Kendo Numeric Text Box

Tags: kendo-ui

I have tried to implement a progress bar in my application. When I used a numeric text box the progress bar is not progressing forward. How to make it progress using a numeric text box. Thanks.

```
<form name="ContactInforForm" action="ContactInformation.html" onsubmit="return ValidateRequiredFields()" method="post">
  <div>

    <table class="forms" style="padding-left:9em">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>Profile Completeness: <span id="completed">20%</span></h4>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="profileCompleteness"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Employee Name:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="FName" id="txtFname" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Employee Id:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="EmpID" id="txtEmpID" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Age:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="Age" id="txtAge" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Contact Phone:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="PrimaryPhone" id="txtPriPhone" />
        </td>
        <td><span id="PPhoneValidationMsg" style="color:red; font-size:smaller; font-weight:bold; "></span></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <button style="width:75px;" type="button" id="btnNext" onclick="ValidateRequiredFields();">Submit</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</form>

<!--Make all the controls into kendo -->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#txtFname").kendoMaskedTextBox({

    });

    $('#txtEmpID').kendoNumericTextBox({

    });


    $('#txtAge').kendoNumericTextBox({

    });


    $('#txtDob').kendoDatePicker({

    });

    $('#txtDesig').kendoMaskedTextBox({});

    $('#txtAdd1').kendoMaskedTextBox({

    });
    $('#txtAdd2').kendoMaskedTextBox({

    });

    $('#drpStates').kendoDropDownList({

    });
    $('#drpCountry').kendoDropDownList({

    });

    $("#txtPriPhone").kendoMaskedTextBox({
      mask: "(000)000-0000"
    });



    $("#btnNext").kendoButton();

    var pb = $("#profileCompleteness").kendoProgressBar({
      type: "chunk",
      chunkCount: 10,
      min: 0,
      max: 10,
      value: 2
    }).data("kendoProgressBar");


    $(".forms input").change(function() {
      var completeness = 2;
      $(".forms input").each(function() {
        if (this.value != "") {
          completeness++;
        }
      });

      pb.value(completeness);
      $("#completed").text((completeness * 10) + "%");


    });
  });
</script>
```

When I changed the kendo numeric text box to masked text box the code seems to work fine. But for  my requirement I require numeric textbox.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of a numeric textbox may not be "". Try something like this:

```
    $(".forms input").change(function () {                
        var completeness = 2;                
        $(".forms input").each(function () {
            if (this.hasClass("k-numerictextbox") && this.value != "0" && this.value != "") {
                completeness++;
            } else if (this.value != "") {
                completeness++;
            }
        });   

        pb.value(completeness);
        $("#completed").text((completeness * 10) + "%");

    });
```

Would be pretty easy to set a break point and see what an empty numeric textbox looks like.